# Kafka broker only exposes PEM (i.e., ca cert, client key, client cert, no JKS), is a Java client possible or feasible?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, pem

I am writing a Java program to communicate with a Kafka broker.  The Kafka broker provides (via REST API) a client certificate, a client key, and a ca certificate.  The KafkaConsumer instantiates successfully, but when the poll() method is executed is throws the 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException
which ultimately traces back to "unable to find valid certificaiton path to requested target."

Internet search seems to indicate Java clients must use JKS but there are a few references (including here in SO) that seem to hint at a way to use keytool and openssl to get such a Java client to work.

I have a Python client that works with this same broker.  The properties used to instantiate a consumer:

... snip ...

```
cons_props = {
    'bootstrap.servers': '%s' % self.kafka_host,
    'group.id': 'mygroup', 'session.timeout.ms': 8000,
    'default.topic.config': { 'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest' },
    'ssl.certificate.location': self.kafka_client_cert,
    'ssl.key.location': self.kafka_client_key,
    'security.protocol': 'ssl', 
    'ssl.ca.location': self.kafka_root_cert }
```

... snip ...

Leveraging the (working) Python properties above and what I've read about Kafka and Java clients, my properties are:

... snip ...

```
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.60.100:9093");
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "mygroup");
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
    StringDeserializer.class.getName());
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
    StringDeserializer.class.getName());
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
consumerProps.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
consumerProps.put("ssl.certificate.location", getClientCertLocation());
consumerProps.put("ssl.key.location", getClientKeyLocation());
consumerProps.put("ssl.ca.location", getRootCertLocation());

workQueue = (KafkaConsumer<String, String>)
            new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(consumerProps);

workQueue.subscribe(Arrays.asList("q_name");

ConsumerRecords<String, String> r;
try {
    r = (ConsumerRecords<String, String>)kc.poll(10);
```

... snip ...

I expected (perhaps naively) that the Java KafkaConsumer ctor would complain if the ssl.* properties were bogus.  But ctor, subscribe both went fine but threw exception with poll method.

As mentioned above, it does seem that I'll have to use JKS but
1) am not sure if that's possible given that I have almost no access to broker configuration, and
2) I do not know if converting the key and certs to jks is possible and, once done, if it will work given broker only "speaks" PEM.

This is my first question posed to SO.  Hopefully it's not too verbose while being somewhat appropriate and helpful to others.  (Surely I'm not the first to try this?)